# Explain the output of the c program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){

int x,y,z;
x=y=z=1;
z=++x||++y&&++z;
printf("%d %d %d \n",x,y,z);
getch();
}
```

the output is coming as 2 1 1 ! i'm not able to get why...if we go by the precedence of the operators this can't be explained. Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logical `or` (`||`) introduces a sequence point. Its left side is evaluated. Then, if and only if that produced 0/false, the right side is evaluated.

In this case, `++x` comes out to 2, so the right side is never evaluated. That, in turn, means `y` and `z` remain as `1`.

Answer (score 3):

The `||` operator short-circuits.  The left-hand operand is evaluated first, and if it evaluates to non-zero, the right operand is never computed.  This also prevents side-effects of evaluation of the right operand.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an || operator, if the LHS turns out to be true, the end result is true. So, it does ++x which turns out to be 1 and the final result is ++x = 2 and z = 1 & y = 1

Answer (score 1):

The boolean `||` short circuits.  That is once it finds a true value it stops evaluating.  Thus all that happens in the z assignment x incremented and z is set to one then

Comment: Nah, it definitely occurs in order: `x` is incremented, and then `z` is set to `1`.

Comment: Interesting, and yet the output of the program is `2 1 1`

Comment: oops, `z` is set to the result of `||`, a boolean, not to `++x`, so yeah, it's `1`.  But `z` is assuredly assigned after `x`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Not so. Even though it seems obvious that the value to be assigned must be calculated before it can be used, the reality is that the assignment operator does *not* create a sequence point. The assignments to `z` and `x` can happen in either order.

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to above answers:

In C/C++ , these operators are the short-circuit operators viz.,  '&&', '||' and '?'(conditional operator).

Do yourself a favor and check out this [excellent wiki page on Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).
Don't miss the [Common usage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#Common_usage) section of the article.